# Magento displaying date from MySQL incorrectly

Tags: magento, date, time

In Magento, I have a phtml that iterates over a collection of a custom model which inherits from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract.  This model has a DB field called 'date'.

When the phtml displays the output of the getDate() function to the browser for each item it is iterating over, most of the time it displays the correct date.   For ambigous dates (date that can be interpreted M/d/Y or d/M/Y, it does it wrong.  I checked date field (datetime) in the MySQL table, and all the dates are stored correctly.  Something in PHP is interpretting the dates wrong once it reads it in from the DB.

For example:

```
In MySQL            => HTML Output => status
2013-12-05 00:00:00 => 5/12/2013   => Wrong
2013-11-30 00:00:00 => 11/30/2013  => Correct
2013-11-06 00:00:00 => 6/11/2013   => Wrong
2013-10-11 00:00:00 => 11/10/2013  => Wrong
etc.
```

I've done google searching and looking in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=magento%20date%20time), but I'm not sure how to fix this issue.  Any ideas?
Thanks.

Update:
I used printLogQuery(true) on the collection to get the query it was executing.  It was as simple as: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `physicians_event` AS `main_table`;

To give more background on how the date is going from the DB to HTML:
In a phtml, I iterate over a custom collection:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getEventCollection() as $_event): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('physicians/event')
                    ->setEvent($_event)
                    ->setTemplate('physicians/event/row.phtml')
                    ->toHtml() ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

getEventCollection looks like this:

```
public function getEventCollection() {
    if ($this->getSortBy() === null) {
        $this->setSortBy('date');
    }

    if ($this->getLimit() === null) {   
        $this->setLimit(10);
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('physicians/event')->getCollection();
    $collection->setOrder($this->getSortBy())
               ->setPageSize($this->getLimit());

    if ($this->getEventType() !== null) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('type', array('eq' => $this->getEventType()));
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

When everything is output as HTML (row.phtml that is rendered for each item in the collection), the date is output like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getEvent()->getFormattedDate('M/d/Y') ?>
```

The getFormattedDate function looks like this:

```
public function getFormattedDate($format = null, $puredate=false) {
    $date = new Zend_Date($this->getDate());
    if ($format === null) {
        $format = 'MMMM d, Y';
    }
    return (!$puredate)?$date->toString($format):$date;
}
```

I believe that is the full story so far.  Ideas?
Thank you again!

Update: further debugging.  Inside of getFormattedDate, I added output statements to trace where the data goes wrong:

```
echo "Collection Item Date: " . var_export($this->getDate()) . "<br/>\n";
$date = new Zend_Date($this->getDate());
echo "Zend Item Date: " . var_export($date,true) . "<br/>\n";
```

The output looked like this:

```
Collection Item Date: '2013-07-06 00:00:00'

Zend Item Date: Zend_Date::__set_state(array(
   '_locale' => 'en_US',
   '_fractional' => 0,
   '_precision' => 3,
   '_unixTimestamp' => '1370563200',
   '_timezone' => 'UTC',
   '_offset' => 0,
   '_syncronised' => 0,
   '_dst' => false,
))
```

Both items are correctly 7/6/2013.  I guess it is getting messed up later in the code.  The trace continues...

I added this:

```
echo "<pre>" . var_export($date->toString($format),true) . "</pre><br />\n";
```

And that had the output of: '6/7/2013', which is WRONG.  So the problem is in how $date->toString($format) operates...

I'm now going through here to see what is off: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats

Comment: I don't actually know the exact query, as everything is retrieved through the Zend/Mage system.  If you make Model that inherits from Zend_DB_Table_Abstract or whatever Magento uses, then perform a derivative of get() on that Model's object, it automatically generates the SQL, queries the DB and creates PHP Objects.

Comment: What collation you used when you create the database? Use `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: It was utf8_general_ci.  I change the DB and the table in question to utf8_unicode_ci but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is there a code snippit that I could possible inject into my code to extract the SQL Query it generates and is sending?  Maybe a Magento/Zend way of getting the current DB connection object, then calling some sort of getLastSQLStatement() function?

Comment: Dear Morfie, many variables can affect date/time, especially if you work under linux. For instance, did you set LC variables in your distro? A few months ago, I prepared a developer guide for Ubuntu Linux installation ( sorry Turkish ). Just visit and check `SUNUCU DİL BİLGİLERİ` section in comments. You will see language settings of the Linux. [http://www.btsoru.com/questions/8421/developerlar-icin-ubuntu-server-nasl-kurulur]

Comment: Also, check the MagePsyco article about Magento date formatting. http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/

Comment: I've added a lot of background info into the question above.  My date formatting info is included.  I believe the time/date/localization variables in linux are set correctly, as other sites on the same box don't have this issue. (RHEL 5.6)

Comment: Btw, I appreciate your help and persistence.

Comment: First try, I doubt about `setSortBy` function. Just remove and try again ( lets see without order ). Also, connect to MySQL and run `SELECT @@lc_time_names;` with same credentials of Magento.

Comment: I ran the lc_time_names query and it returned en_US.  I removed the setSortBy and it didn't fix the issue. :(  So strange, right?

Comment: Ok, lets change timezone settings of the Magento. Find `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php` and open up, then look at the `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE` constant. Temporarly change like `Europe/Istanbul`

Comment: I changed it to Europe/Istanbul from en_US.  No affect on the issue.

Comment: Also there are some other variables in same file related with date formats. Could you please check and change them as well?

Comment: I'll go and take a look.  The issue is that most dates ARE formatted correctly already.  Only the ambiguous ones are incorrect.  The ones that are before the 13th of any month.  July 6th (2013-07-06) is supposed to come up as 7/6/2013, but comes up as 6/7/2013.   However July 20th (2013-07-20) comes up as 7/20/2013, which is correct.

Comment: I added some data tracing above.

Comment: Dear Morfie, please don't work too much for that. As I can see, there is a variable inside Zend Date which is `_unixTimestamp`. Just convert with `gmdate('m-d-Y', _unixTimestamp)`

Comment: Wait a sec, that unitimestamp isn't correct which is output `06.07.2013` based on the `m.d.Y`, is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue!!!

The problem was with this:

```
$date = new Zend_Date($this->getDate());
```

It didn't like passing the DB Model's date into the Zend_Date constructor.  Zend_Date was interpreting it incorrectly.  After reading into the docs on Zend_Date, I learned that it prefers unix timestamps better.

I changed that line in getFormatted Date to look like this:

```
$date = new Zend_Date(strtotime($this->getDate()));
```

Now all the dates are working correctly!

Comment: zend date , it is! perfect!